# tutorials on migrating SQL 2008 BI-stack to Azure SQL Data Warehouse?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

Are there any tutorials available on the subject of migrating from an existing BI-stack based on SQL Server 2008 to Azure SQL Data Warehouse? I'm specifically interested in best practices with regards to how to handle cross database joins on non-premium tiers (our existing procedures and UDFs are full of joins on multiple database objects) and how to migrate existing SSAS cubes and its related programmability and ETL.

Comment: This type of question (asking for tutorials/books/etc) is off topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Sure. However, Microsoft specifically refers to StackOverflow if there are questions regarding Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

Answer (score 2):

What BI-stack are you using? This will determine your next steps for the actual BI tools.

Specifically for cross-database queries when moving to the cloud, the guidance is to move the databases into schemas and then update your scripts to use schema based (2 part names) vs. database (3 part names) when referencing objects. For example, if you have staging and production databases you can simply move your staging objects into a [staging] schema within a single database.

Azure SQL Data Warehouse is commonly used as a backing store for SSAS cubes (MOLAP/ROLAP/Tabular mode). In the Azure cloud, customers have created IaaS SQL Server VMs to host ETL process (SSIS) and cubes (SSAS) with direct connections to SQL Data Warehouse.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matt. I realize I cannot answer this question without incurring more minus points since SO is not really equipped for this type of discussion. I took the liberty of "migrating" this question to the msdn forums, hope you don't mind. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b17c8815-ce60-4e89-a1cc-f498d918b4b3/tutorials-on-migrating-sql-2008-bistack-to-azure-sql-data-warehouse?forum=AzureSQLDataWarehouse